# .eml format data import into elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fscrawler

Now I have mails in .eml format that need to be parsed, and then import elasticsearch, through fscrawler, but fscrawler can not scan the sender and recipient information, how can I solve it

Comment: Could you share an eml file which does not work?

Answer (score 0):

FSCrawler extracts everything it can from the eml format.
See [this discussion](https://github.com/dadoonet/fscrawler/issues/948) for more details.